# Add item to list if not already exists

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm new to Python and got following problem:

```
a = [[0,abc,1],[0,def,1]]

b = [abc,jkl]
```

Output should be:

```
c = [[0,abc,1],[0,def,1],[0,jkl,1]]
```

Can anyone help me out there?

Comment: What's the logic between the input and the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with the following code:

```
In [3]: a = [[0,'abc',1],[0,'def',1]]
In [4]: b = ['abc','jkl']
In [5]: c = a[:]
In [6]: c.extend([[0,e,1] for e in b if e not in [x for _,x,_ in a]])
In [7]: c
Out[8]: [[0, 'abc', 1], [0, 'def', 1], [0, 'jkl', 1]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @VigneshKalai by doing "c = a[:]" i'm coping a to c.

Comment: @VigneshKalai I edited it some time ago, before your coment :)

Comment: one more beginner question: does " \_,x,\_ " mean: "just look at x, ignore the rest" ??

Comment: This statement [x for _,x,_ in a] loops each element of a. Each element of a is a list of three elements, so each element will look like [a,b,c]. As the only element i'm interested in is the element in the middle, I can write _,x,_, but the behavior will be the same as if I write a,x,c.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
>>> a = [[0,'abc',1],[0,'def',1]]
>>> b = ['abc','jkl']
>>> c = a[:]
>>> for i in b:
...     if [0,i,1] not in a:
...             c.append([0,i,1])
... 
>>> c
[[0, 'abc', 1], [0, 'def', 1], [0, 'jkl', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **not in** to check if it contains or not

```
a = [[0,abc,1],[0,def,1]]

b = [abc,jkl]

c = []

for i in a:
    if i not in c:
       c.append(i)
for j in b:
    if j not in c:
       c.append(j)
```

Comment: This is not working at all. You just add all items from a and b to list c.